# assign names for for loop generated files related to POSIXct

Tags: r

I am try to creating multiple data sets with increasing days between certain time points. I also want to give them the new names. However, according to the code below, the file name sometime is in the format of b2015-11-10 23:00:00. I can view them by clicking in r studio environment but the file name is not valid in the code.
  For example, I try to give them a new name
    abc <- b2015-11-10 23:00:00 
but the error pops out: Error: unexpected numeric constant in "abc <- b2015-12-22 23". Any ideas? It would be great if I can assign file names such as a1,a2,a3...in the for loop at the beginning, then I don't need to assign names again. Thanks very much!

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2015-08-26")
end <- as.POSIXct("2015-12-24")
for(i in seq(from=start, by=60*60*24*7, to=end)) {
      bbbi <- subset(bbact_2015day, ACT_DATE >="2015-08-26" & ACT_DATE <= i)
      class(i) <- class(start) # correct i type
      assign(paste0("b", i), aaigpa[,c(1,4,12)] )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not worried about descriptive names, you could create a variable, `j`, that you iterate within the `for` loop. Then, you use `j` within the `assign` function:

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2015-08-26")
end <- as.POSIXct("2015-12-24")
j = 1
for(i in seq(from=start, by=60*60*24*7, to=end)) {
    bbbi <- subset(bbact_2015day, ACT_DATE >="2015-08-26" & ACT_DATE <= i)
    class(i) <- class(start) # correct i type
    assign(paste0("b", j), aaigpa[,c(1,4,12)] )
    j = j+1
}
```

Alternatively, if you want more descriptive names, you could use:

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2015-08-26")
end <- as.POSIXct("2015-12-24")
for(i in seq(from=start, by=60*60*24*7, to=end)) {
    bbbi <- subset(bbact_2015day, ACT_DATE >="2015-08-26" & ACT_DATE <= i)
    class(i) <- class(start) # correct i type
    assign(paste0("b", format(i, '%Y%m%d'), #format date label
           aaigpa[,c(1,4,12)] )
}
```